# Using CSS3 Variable Not Working for set a background-image url?

Tags: css, web-frontend, css-variables

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6ZIU.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0cyG.png)

Hi guys, I use the css3 variable want to set the background img url dynamic, but it doesn't work for me.  but it's worked if I set a color value to a variable and use it, and if it's in backgroud attribute, it's just like  `url(var(--src))` and it didn't work...  how should I do?

because I want upload the pictures of my project to a cloud server, and reference the image link from the server. but in some cases I need change the server domain and I don't want change it one by one in all referenced files. so my plan is create a base css style, and all others css file need import this, in this base css, declare a variable to save the server domain, and then other css files can read this var.  but it doesn't seem to work.  Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```css
:root {
  --url: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQCRdy-xqdYAs_g95P-gsnPcw8FgUYK-SqSq814BY6i55piXZrG"); 
  
}

.test {
  background: var(--url);
  padding:50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
</div>
```